# Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch on combo Box - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**Introduction**:
I have prior experience in programming (C, C++, Java), however, this is my first time using Excel VBA.

**Some background**:
I am trying to initialize a combo box with a list from a sheet called `ORI_LIST` but every time I run it I get `Run Time Error 13`. Any information on this would be great.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim cLoc As Range
    Dim OriSheetList As Worksheets

    Set OriSheetList = Worksheets("ORI_LIST")

    For Each cLoc In OriSheetList.Range("CRI")
        With Me.COMBO_ORILIST
            .AddItem cLoc.Value
        End With
    Next cLoc
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, the combo box has 1413 choices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah this is a silly one but you want `Dim OriSheetList As Worksheet`.

The `Worksheet` object is singular. The collection of all the sheets in the workbook is plural. It would be nice if there was a little more help from the IDE on these issues but alas that is the world of VBA.

Comment: Thank You. Now i am getting error 70 permission denied. But after some gooling I found the answer. I filled in row sources in properties. removed it now i am good.

Comment: I'm surprised you got an error after fixing that. It worked for me. But either way. Glad to help.